# only one file system is placed in my computer

Tags: partitioning

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I had partitioned 320 GB as follows,

1. 77GB,ext2,mount=/boot
2. 77GB,ext3,mount=/
3. 77GB,ext4,mount=/home
4. 77GB,ReiserFS,mount=/usr
5. 13 GB swap.

In this partitions I can't use any areas except `/home`. **How can I re-partition?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use e.g. `GParted` partitoning program to resize your partitions. But you can't just simply resize mounted partitions, so boot up a Live CD, install GParted with

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Start gparted and resize your partitions.

Answer (score 0):

well there is a good reason for such partition process.I will explain them as my level best.

**swap** :  swap partitions are used to support virtual memory. In other words, data is written to a swap partition when there is not enough RAM to store the data your system is processing. That can speed up processing of data (usually swap recommended to give twice of your RAM)

**/boot** : /boot/ contains the operating system kernel (which allows your system to boot), along with files used during the bootstrap process. For most users, a 250 MB boot partition is sufficient.

**/usr**  : The /usr directory holds the majority of software content on Linux system. For an installation of the default set of software, allocate at least 4 GB of space. If you are a software developer or something who deals with huge sized applications and space then you'd better to go for extension of space.

but there is a problem with separate /usr partition that is the boot process becomes much more complex, and in some situations (like installations on iSCSI drives), might not work at all.
If you would like to know more about partition schemes then I suggest you to must read this : http://tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_03_01.html

If you shrink the size of those partitions then you can do that from gparted which you can install from either software center & terminal.

from terminal `sudo apt-get install gparted`

If you would like to shrink the size of the partition , just open gparted and then select the partition with right-click but as I know you cant do it from installed system . you must do it from live system .